# unsupported file format with boto s3.download_file

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, format, boto3

When i try to download s3 object from my bucket using [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/guide/s3-example-download-file.html#downloading-a-file)

My code :

```
import boto3
import botocore
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
BUCKET_NAME = 'prod-data' 
objects = ["e73ed280","c09987edc6d3"]
for obj in objects :
    try:
        pathname = "/home/praveen/Downloads/" + obj + ".json"
        s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(obj, pathname)
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
            print(obj ,"  -->" , "The object does not exist.")
        else:
            raise
```

Result : Above code runs successfully and downloads the fil s3 to my local filepath $pathname

Problem : After download complete i cannot open/extract this file , the problem I shows below picture.

Note : Type of the file  ["e73ed280","c09987edc6d3"] json format.

Update : Found metadata of the s3 file.

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'KH7K001CV3T', 'HostId': 'v9FivT1xxQc1BV0ajchRThUmiMGq2JYSrTDYs=', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': 'v9F=IZVqqDCtDhV0ajchRThUmiMGq2JY=K0TYs=', 'x-amz-request-id': 'KH=Q8CV3T', 'date': 'Tue, 12 Apr 2022 02:16:49 GMT', 'x-amz-replication-status': 'COMPLETED', 'last-modified': 'Fri, 11 Feb 2022 04:06:00 GMT', 'etag': '"e73ed280"', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'x-amz-version-id': 'CE8O0Flh9yZzP5PZo9SluXzni57CmSZa', 'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'server': 'AmazonS3', 'content-length': '133251'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'AcceptRanges': 'bytes', 'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 11, 4, 6, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'ContentLength': 133251, 'ETag': '"e73ed280"', 'VersionId': 'CE8O0Flh9P5PZo9SznimSZa', 'ContentEncoding': 'gzip', 'ContentType': 'application/json', 'Metadata': {}, 'ReplicationStatus': 'COMPLETED'}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you opening a .json file in an extraction app?

Comment: I tired to open my download file in sublime , it opens as binary format.When checked the file format using file command :  `$  file c09987edc6d3`
`c09987edc6d3: gzip compressed data, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 1751919`

Comment: I'm confused, is it a json file or a gzip file?

Comment: If you download the files using the Amazon S3 management console, are you able to open/read the files correctly?

Comment: Yes @JohnRotenstein I can able to open and read the file correctly when I download it from console.

Comment: Web browsers automatically decompress gzip data, but other methods of downloading may not. Curl for example requires `--compressed` option to decompress.

Comment: Thanks @jordanm, I went through the  [link](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client) documentation i cant find anything like  compressed

Comment: Rather than "opening" the file, if you `cat` or `head` it from the command line, is the contents human-readable?

Comment: You can use the python gzip library to decompress gzip content. The commonly used `requests` library does this automatically, but I think you are right that the boto3 s3 library does not.